# When using filters on the main Stack Exchange site, why is there less information available about a question?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I like to utilize [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/popular) at the main site at stackexchange.com to view questions for subjects that interest me or that I feel I might be able to contribute in. The filters there seem quicker than going to each site and then narrowing it down to the tag that I wish to view.

My expectation would have been that the view from stackexchange.com using a filter would be similar to the information available when I am actually at the site viewing questions with a certain tag. However, this seems to not be the case. Specifically, questions viewed via Stack Exchange filters instead of at the site + tag seem to lack the following pieces of information:

1. How many votes the question has received (main difference imo)
2. ## of views
3. visible rep of person asking the question (clicking on a link to their profile isn't the same)
4. on hover description of a tag
5. An extra visual cue (red border usually) that a question lacks an answer

I also don't see them as options I can toggle on when creating or editing a filter.

Answer (score 2):

The number of votes is shown when viewing the "hot" tab ([example](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19474/emacs-questions?sort=hot)), and the number of answers is shown when viewing any other tab ([example](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19474/emacs-questions?sort=newest)).

We de-emphasize the vote count and hide the view count and asker's reputation because these metrics aren't especially useful when comparing questions from different sites. For example, Stack Overflow questions will almost always have way more views than similar-quality questions from other sites.